# Авторизация на сайте Python + Requests

Tags: python, парсер, авторизация, requests

Ребята подскажите пожалуйста, не могу пройти авторизацию на сайте

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#НАЧАЛО Авторизация на сайте

#ссылка
url_login = 'https://opt.euroauto.ru/user/auth'
#браузер
user_agent_val = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) ' \
                 'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                 'Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'
#открытие сессии
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url_login, headers = {
    'User-Agent': user_agent_val
})

session.headers.update({'Referer':url_login})
session.headers.update({'User-Agent':user_agent_val})
_xsrf = session.cookies.get('_xsrf', domain="opt.euroauto.ru")

# Осуществляем вход с помощью метода POST с указанием необходимых данных
post_request = session.post(url_login, {
     'backUrl': 'https://opt.euroauto.ru/',
     'login': '*логин*',
     'passw': '*пароль*',
     '_xsrf':_xsrf,
})
with open("hh_success.html","w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(post_request.text)
#Конец Авторизация на сайте
```

Comment: Ну как минимум у вас логин два раза повторяется

Comment: <input id="form-login" name="login" placeholder="Логин" 
<input id="form-passw" type="password" name="login"

Comment: Эти name из этого html-кода никак не используются сайтом. Да и запрос на неправильный адрес отправляете, откройте инспектор сети и изучите отправляемый сайтом запрос

Comment: Действительно если не ошибаюсь форма отправляется 'https://opt.euroauto.ru/user/auth'
формы: login' и 'passw', но не помогло увы

Comment: Попробуйте лучше `selenium`.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендуемую вам прочитать и придерживаться pep8 ([на русском](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html) или [официальная документация](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

Я привёл ваш код к более правильному виду:

```py
import requests
import sys


def main():
    base_url = 'https://opt.euroauto.ru'
    login = base_url + '/user/auth'

    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent
    # для ваших запросов используйте такую форму:
    #  User-Agent: <название-продукта> / <версия продукта> <комментарий>
    user_agent = 'nameless-project / 0.0.1 (Python {0})'.format(sys.version[:5])

    # открытие сессии
    session = requests.Session()

    # обновление headers сессии
    session.headers.update({'User-Agent': user_agent})

    # автооризация
    resp = session.post(login, {
        'login': '<логин>',
        'passw': '<пароль>',
        'recaptcha': '<результат-после-успешного-прохождения-капчи>'})

    # запись ответа в файл
    with open('success_login.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(str(resp.json()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

вывод программы:

#### success_login.txt

```
{'result': False, 'message': 'Необходимо пройти проверку "Я не робот"', 'data': None}
```

---

Проблема в том, что для регистрации нужно пройти капчу, если вы не можете знать ответ на капчу, то у вас ничего не получится.
Вот немного справочной инфотрмации: [Обработка Google Recaptcha с запросами Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324741/handle-google-recaptcha-with-python-requests), [Документация для проверки результатов капчи](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

Comment: А для чего делать свой User-Agent? Не лучше указывать от браузера, т.к. сайты могут отклонить запрос из-за "неправильного" User-Agent? Кст, сам `requests` пишет себя в User-Agent. PS. для добавления только одного заголовка мне кажется лучше так `session.headers['User-Agent'] = user_agent`

Comment: @gil9red, 1 - мы говорим кто конкретный сайт, который прекрасно принимает такой вид. 2 - это стандарт user-agent-а, просто браузеры имеют расширенный вид, который не нужен для собственных запросов. 3 - user-agent не обязателен, но в коде вопроса он был, поэтому я его переделал и оставил

Comment: @gil9red, для единичного обновления `session.headers['User-Agent'] = user_agent` будет лучше, в коде вопроса было несколько параметров, я убрал ненужные и не думал о том чтобы сделать идеальный код.